# Mockito Controller Test I'm getting error

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

all I'm trying to test my controller. But I'm getting error.

> Wanted but not invoked: accountService.findAccount("9090");
> -> at com.ontavio.bank.ControllerTests.givenId_Cash_thenReturnJson(ControllerTests.java:67)
>
> However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
> accountService.cash(
> "9090",
> com.ontavio.bank.model.CashTransaction@2f408960 );

```
    @PostMapping("/cash/{accountNumber}")
    public ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> cash(@PathVariable String accountNumber, @RequestBody CashTransaction cashTransactionRequest) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(accountService.cash(accountNumber, cashTransactionRequest));
    }

---
    public TransactionStatus cash(String accountNumber, CashTransaction cashTransaction) {
            Account account = this.findAccount(accountNumber);
            cashTransaction.setType(TransactionTypes.CASH_TRANSACTION.getRelation());
            account.post(cashTransaction);
            accountRepository.save(accountMapper.AccountToAccountEntity(account));
    
            return TransactionStatus.createTransactionStatus(HttpStatus.OK, "");
    }
----
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ControllerTests  {

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    private AccountController accountController;

    @Mock
    private AccountService accountService;

    @Mock
    private AccountMapper accountMapper;

    @Mock
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;


    @Test
    public void givenId_Cash_thenReturnJson()
    throws Exception {
        
        Account account = new Account("James Harden", "9090");

        CashTransaction cashTransaction = new CashTransaction(100.0);

        AccountEntity accountEntity = new AccountEntity();
        accountEntity.setOwner(account.getOwner());
        accountEntity.setAccountNumber(account.getAccountNumber());

        TransactionStatus transactionStatus = new TransactionStatus();
        transactionStatus.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.name());


        doReturn(account).when(accountService).findAccount( "9090");
        doReturn(transactionStatus).when(accountService).cash("9090", depositTransaction);
        doReturn(accountEntity).when(accountRepository).save(accountEntity);

        ResponseEntity<TransactionStatus> result = accountController.cash( "9090", cashTransaction);
        verify(accountService, times(1)).findAccount("9090");
        assertEquals("OK", result.getBody().getStatus());
    }
```

Comment: apparently, that method wasn't called, or it wasn't called with that parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing

```
....
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ControllerTests  {
.....
```

above your ControllerTest class. Also i would suggest to use @Autowired instead of @Spy and @InjectMocks, and Annotate your mocked Service,Mapper and repository with @MockBean

OR (depending on your use case)

Use the annotation

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

then you have a Mockito test which does not start the spring context. You could remove @SpringBootTest @ContextConfiguration @AutoConfigureMockMvc then. You don´t need @AutoConfigureMockMvc anyways since you do not execute a http call, but call the RestControllers method directly. I dont see why you would need the spring context in your test, so I would prefer to use the Mockito Test. It is much faster since the applicationContext does not start.

Mixing Spring and Mockito testing environment works, but can make for weird circumstances. I generally try to stay in one. Either test a class and mock everything with Mockito or write an integration Test and use the Spring utilities.